# exercise power vs.exert power

Tags: differences

What is the difference between 'exerting power' and 'exercising power'? I've heard both in very similar contexts, and cannot tell if there's a nuance of meaning that I've missed. Dictionaries didn't help either.

Comment: Dictionaries didn't help? I find that hard to believe!

Answer (score 1):

To **exercise** power would be to use power.

To **exert** power would be to make a forceful effort to use power.

So, the nuance affects how they would be used in a sentence.

> The manager **exercised** his power over his employees by firing one of them as an example.

> The body builder **exerted** his power to lift the two-hundred-pound weight.

In those two examples there is a connotation that the manager used his power in an effortless manner, whereas the body builder had to make an effort to use his power; which is why **exerted** was chosen instead of **used.**

Answer (score 0):

"To exercise" implies no special norm in the wielding of power, whereas "to exert" carries the idea of exercising power with a will.
This is clear from the definition in SOED.

- exert **4** *v.t.* Exercise, apply, bring to bear, (a quality, force, etc.) esp. with considerable effort or effect.